# How do I configure ant on Android to include an external jar without exporting it in the apk?

Tags: android, ant, jar

I Have an application that uses a shared jar library located on my platform. I would like to build my project off my platform. To do so, I need to include the jar file in compilation.

This works in Eclipse - I add the library to the project, and everything works fine. I encounter a problem after building with ant. Ant requires that I include the jar file in my libs directory. However if I include it there, it is exported into the apk. When I deploy this locally built apk to my device, I get runtime errors complaining about multiple symbol definitions.

Comment: I have a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27362888/183123. You may have encountered a similar challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a custom_rules.xml file to your project to exclude jar after compilation from apk. See here [Exclude dependency jar file from apk when using Ant for Android](http://0xwalkingice.blogspot.com/2013/05/exclude-dependency-jar-file-from-apk.html)