# How do I configure my Android project in Eclipse to exclude a library in the libs directory from export?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I have a series of libraries included in my Android project. One of the libraries is a system lib that I do not want statically linked, and I do not want exported into my apk.

At present I have located the external library in my libs directory so that ant picks it up. However, doing so means that Eclipse doesn't provide me with the option to *not* export the library with the apk.

My question is, how do I prevent Eclipse from exporting a library in the libs directory?

Comment: which build system are you using?  ant, gradle, or maven?  You are going to want to add a build step to remove the lib from the /libs directory before packaging.

Comment: Whatever the eclipse-ADT uses internally. Unfortunately I'm not sure what that is.